# Bootloop when installing HyperV

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v

i am using Windows 10 and i am trying to use Hyper-V for Android Emulation.
Everytime i am installing Hyper-V my computer gets stuck in a reboot loop (until automatic repair jumps in).

I have tried the following things:

- Boot Safemode: Works
- Disable Vt-d and boot: Works
- Boot Safemode and uninstall Hyper-V again: Works
- Enable Hotswap: No difference
- Uninstall Visual Studio incl. Android Emulation: No difference
- Update ALL drivers, including BIOS firmware, chipset etc.: No difference

System Spec:

- Intel i7-4790 (Haswell)
- Intel Z97 Board (Sabertooth Mark 2)
- Main Drive: SSD Samsung Evo

Other informations i found in Eventlog i get this error shortly before the critical halt:

1. Source: Kernel Boot, Event-ID 124, Message: The virtual safemode (VSM) was not initilazed (rough translation)
2. Source: Hyper-V-Hypervisor, Event-ID 41, Message: Hypervisor launch failed; Either VMX not present or not enabled in BIOS.
3. Source: Kernel Power, Event-ID 41

Answer (score 0):

I was cursed with this same issue after trying to install Hyper-V, below is what I did to fix it.

1. Enable Virtualization in BIOS.
2. Boot into Safe Mode.
3. Disable Windows Defender in gpedit(https://www.windowscentral.com/how-permanently-disable-windows-defender-windows-10)
4. Install all Hyper-V components.
5. Reboot into Safe Mode again.
6. Uninstall all Hyper-V components.
7. Reboot into Safe Mode again.(at this point I got an error that it could not complete my changes and was rolling them back)
8. Reboot into Normal Mode.(Got the same error message about not being able to apply my changes and reverting them)
9. Ensure all Hyper-V components are unchecked in the Windows Features

Comment: So are you saying that “Uninstall all Hyper-V components” is the answer? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your post to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I had success with disabling virtualization in the BIOS. Boot loop before but after disabling virtualization my system booted normally and HyperV worked. My system APU is mobile AMD Ryzen 2500U Vega 8.